# How to customize the "sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar" control?

Tags: sapui5

I developed a SAPUI5 page with a list of items and a search feature using the [control `sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar). The framework defines automatically a text for the button which triggers the search and also for a placeholder that appears as default in the search field.

I would like to customize this in order to have better control of its content and a better multi language management with i18n settings. How can I do this customization? I looked at the documentation but it does not mention a property which I can easily make this change.

[image: screenshot filter bar SAPUI5]

Follows a piece of code that implements this part of the View

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<fb:FilterBar xmlns:fb="sap.ui.comp.filterbar" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  id="filterBar"
  search=".onSearch"
  showRestoreButton="false"
  showClearButton="true"
  showFilterConfiguration="false"
>
  <fb:filterGroupItems>
    <fb:FilterGroupItem
      groupName="__$INTERNAL$"
      name="A"
      label="{i18n>workstreamsOptions}"
      partOfCurrentVariant="true"
      visibleInFilterBar="true"
    >
      <fb:control>
        <ComboBox id="WorkStreamCombobox" change=".onChange">
          <core:Item key="001" text="{i18n>ws1}" />
          <core:Item key="002" text="{i18n>ws2}" />
          <core:Item key="003" text="{i18n>ws3}" />
          <core:Item key="004" text="{i18n>ws4}" />
          <core:Item key="005" text="{i18n>ws5}" />
          <core:Item key="006" text="{i18n>ws6}" />
          <core:Item key="007" text="{i18n>ws7}" />
          <core:Item key="008" text="{i18n>ws8}" />
          <core:Item key="009" text="{i18n>ws9}" />
        </ComboBox>
      </fb:control>
    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
    <fb:FilterGroupItem
      groupName="__$INTERNAL$"
      name="B"
      label="{i18n>typeOfInterface}"
      labelTooltip="Tooltip Example"
      partOfCurrentVariant="true"
      visibleInFilterBar="true"
    >
      <fb:control>
        <ComboBox id="TypeCombobox" change=".onChange">
          <core:Item key="001" text="{i18n>typeInbound}" />
          <core:Item key="002" text="{i18n>typeOutbound}" />
          <core:Item key="003" text="{i18n>typeNotClassified}" />
        </ComboBox>
      </fb:control>
    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
  </fb:filterGroupItems>
</fb:FilterBar>
<!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly you are looking to overwrite and customize the placeholder for the default search ..

It can be controlled by the following code.

```
    onToggleSearchField: function (oEvent) {
        var oSearchField = this.oFilterBar.getBasicSearch();
        var oBasicSearch;
        if (!oSearchField) {
            oBasicSearch = new SearchField({
                showSearchButton: false,
                placeholder:"Custom Placeholder"
            });
        } else {
            oSearchField = null;
        }

        this.oFilterBar.setBasicSearch(oBasicSearch);

        oBasicSearch.attachBrowserEvent("keyup", function (e) {
                if (e.which === 13) {
                    this.onSearch();
                }
            }.bind(this)
        );
    },
```

and Initialize the onToggleSearchField() in your onInit() function.

Customizing the same via i18n... Set your text in your i18n and control the placeholder accordingly using the following logic.

```
this.getView().getModel('i18n').getResourceBundle().getText(
                            'Your PlaceHolder Name from i18n')
```

Thanks,

Abhi